# Error Sending XML file by CURL to WebServices

Tags: php

I'm trying to send by POST method a XML through of CURL to authenticated webServices, but for some reason the server is rejecting the XML file, me giving me an error 500, however another WebService than by GET method, not have problem. The following code is i'm trying.

```
  <?php
  $request_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?> 
  <FiltroLicitaciones xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"> 
  <CantidadRegistro>10</CantidadRegistro> 
  <Texto>memo</Texto> 
  <CodigoRegion xsi:nil=\"true\" /> 
  <CodigoEstado>1</CodigoEstado> 
  <TipoFecha>FechaPublicacion</TipoFecha> 
  <FechaDesde>2011-06-01T00:00:00</FechaDesde> 
  <FechaHasta>2011-08-01T00:00:00</FechaHasta> 
  </FiltroLicitaciones>";

  //Initialize handle and set options 
  $username = 'user'; 
  $password = 'pass'; 
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.mercadopublico.cl/movil/licitaciones/porFecha');  
 //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/server.php"); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_xml);

   $result = curl_exec($ch); 

   curl_close($ch); 

   print_r($result); 

   ?>
```

I don't know if will be a error for XML malformed, but server return me a random 500 error with the following header:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the      server logs for more details.
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 1047
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 30 Jul 2012 23:53:05 GMT
```

I did a test in the local server, for see as the data came, the following the result this is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date: Mon, 30 Jul 2012 23:41:50 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Fedora) 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.14 
Content-Length: 2450 
Connection: close 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 

Array 
( 
 [GLOBALS] => Array 
 *RECURSION* 
  [_POST] => Array 
    ( 
        [<?xml version] => "1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
        <FiltroLicitaciones xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
        <CantidadRegistro>10</CantidadRegistro> 
        <Texto>memo</Texto> 
        <CodigoRegion xsi:nil="true" /> 
        <CodigoEstado>1</CodigoEstado> 
        <TipoFecha>FechaPublicacion</TipoFecha> 
        <FechaDesde>2011-06-01T00:00:00</FechaDesde> 
        <FechaHasta>2011-08-01T00:00:00</FechaHasta> 
        </FiltroLicitaciones> 
    ) 

[_GET] => Array 
    ( 
    ) 

[_COOKIE] => Array 
    ( 
    ) 

[_FILES] => Array 
    ( 
    ) 

[_ENV] => Array 
    ( 
    ) 

[_REQUEST] => Array 
    ( 
        [<?xml version] => "1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
        <FiltroLicitaciones xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
        <CantidadRegistro>10</CantidadRegistro> 
        <Texto>memo</Texto> 
        <CodigoRegion xsi:nil="true" /> 
        <CodigoEstado>1</CodigoEstado> 
        <TipoFecha>FechaPublicacion</TipoFecha> 
        <FechaDesde>2011-06-01T00:00:00</FechaDesde> 
        <FechaHasta>2011-08-01T00:00:00</FechaHasta> 
        </FiltroLicitaciones> 
    ) 

[_SERVER] => Array 
    ( 
        [HTTP_HOST] => localhost 
        [HTTP_ACCEPT] => */* 
        [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 469 
        [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
        [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin 
        [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => <address>Apache/2.2.22 (Fedora) Server at localhost Port 80</address> 

        [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.22 (Fedora) 
        [SERVER_NAME] => localhost 
        [SERVER_ADDR] => ::1 
        [SERVER_PORT] => 80 
        [REMOTE_ADDR] => ::1 
        [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html 
        [SERVER_ADMIN] => root@localhost 
        [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/html/server.php 
        [REMOTE_PORT] => 37712 
        [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1 
        [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1 
        [REQUEST_METHOD] => POST 
        [QUERY_STRING] =>  
        [REQUEST_URI] => /server.php 
        [SCRIPT_NAME] => /server.php 
        [PHP_SELF] => /server.php 
        [PHP_AUTH_USER] => user 
        [PHP_AUTH_PW] => pass 
        [REQUEST_TIME] => 1343691710 
    )
```

)

I hope can you help me.

Thanks.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not sure if the 500 error is from the xml but, as I see in your code the xml has no url variable :

```
  myxml=<xml></xml>
```

Because as you can see from the response the url paramenter has become

```
 [<?xml version] => "1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

and this is wrong.

If the api docs didn't specified any url parameters then you should probably set the right curl header :

```
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/xml");
```

Like this the server knows what to expect

Answer (score 0):

Note this part of your sample dump:

```
  [_POST] => Array 
    ( 
        [<?xml version]
```

Your XML data was interpreted as a form-type data upload, with a field name of `<?xml version`. This destroyed your XML's structure, leading to a parse error on the server you're submitting this to.

Comment: Ok thanks, how could I remove this: [<? Xml version] and replace with this <? Xml version before sending the XML to server. 

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Read below url first i think this is very use full to you

Sending XML files to a Webservice (Using cURL)

http://softwaredevelopmentindia.wordpress.com/2007/07/09/sending-xml-files-to-a-webservice-using-curl/

or try this

Calling Web Services. Great fun!! … when it works. One of the biggest challenges is to send the XML document and get the response back, an XML document in particular. I have come up with a PHP function that hides all the necessary logic from theuser and handles the posting of the XML document and returns whatever the server responds. It relies on PHP’s cURL library (so you need it properly configured on your server in order to work). All you need to do is create the XML document, choose the URL (and port) to which you want to post the XML document and the function takes care of the rest. Below is the function code. As you can see, the function can handle SSL-enabled servers, something that provides a great advantage, since many Web services run on HTTPS.

// open a http channel, transmit data and return received buffer

```
function xml_post($post_xml, $url, $port)
{
$user_agent = $_SERVER[’HTTP_USER_AGENT’];
$ch = curl_init(); // initialize curl handle
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set url to post to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // Fail on errors
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // allow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port); //Set the port number
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15); // times out after 15s
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_xml); // add POST fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
if($port==443)
{
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
}
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
```

The example below shows how the function works, by posting a XML document of the form

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”iso-8859-1″?>

<Document> 

  <Message> 

     Your Name  

  </Message>

</Document>
```

to a “listener” script, which takes the XML document and returns a reply (another XML document). In this case, the listener is very simple. All it does is replace the “Message” tag with “Reply” and print the resulting XML. Of course, the listener can do all sorts of things in response to the POST.

```
<?php 

   if ( !isset( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ) )

   {

      $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents( ‘php://input’ ); 

   } 

   $xml = str_replace(”Message”,”Reply” , $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);  

   print((trim($xml)));

?>
```